# How do i match two table in mysql and get the value which is note matched?

Tags: php, mysql

Please refer to the below link that I have attached an image file and I have two tables in MySQL database and I want know how to find the userEmpNo which does not match with each other table ?

I have tried **array_diff**, **array_diff_assoc()** which is not work for me. please help

[This is data image file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQ1cj.jpg)

Comment: what have u tried ? code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you want to select all userEmpNo that doesn't exists in the other table, then you can do it on the SQL side, and use NOT EXISTS() :

```
SELECT * From TableA t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TableB s
                 WHERE s.userEmpNo = t.userEmpNo)
```

Or join:

```
SELECT * From TableA t
LEFT JOIN TableB s
 ON(s.userEmpNo = t.userEmpNo)
WHERE s.userEmpNo is null
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. can please explain what did you mean by t and s ?

Comment: T and S are aliases, now every time I want to call TableA.Column I can write t.Column , same goes for TableB. You define aliases in the FROM part. @Rimaz

Comment: Ok thanks so much,  so how do you write this statement in codeigniter ?

Comment: Thank you so much for help. your query is perfect which working now.